# Javascript FF Slow Chrome/Safari FAST

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, raphael

Here's an interesting conundrum, I have a javascript data viz that runs great in Safari/Chrome and even runs alright in IE. But Firefox it is really really slow. I've noted the section of code that seems to be slowing things down.

The variable stats is `var stats = [{"team":"IND","player":"Andrew Luck","position":"QB","round":1,"choice":1,"size":66}, ... ];`

Here's the full code. The problem area is at the bottom. Does anyone have any idea why Firefox has problems running this?

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var paper = Raphael("graph",390, 1600);

        var selectedteam;
        for (var i = 0 ; i <= 252; i++) {
            var s = stats[i].size*.3;
            stats[i].circles = paper.circle(stats[i].round*50-20, stats[i].choice*20, s*.75)
                .attr({
                        "fill": "RGB(" + (89*.3-s)*14 + ", " + s*8 + ", 100)",
                        "stroke": "RGB(255,255,255)"
                })
            stats[i].circles.player = stats[i].player;
            stats[i].circles.team = stats[i].team;
            stats[i].circles.position = stats[i].position;
            stats[i].circles.mouseout(function() {
                for (var lines in stats) {
                    stats[lines].circles.animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
                }
            });
            stats[i].circles.mouseover(function() {
                selectedteam = this.team;
                $('#error').empty().html("<div><p>" + this.player + ", " + this.position + "</p><p>" + this.team + "</p></div>");   
 //****THIS FOR LOOP IS REALLY REALLY SLOW IN FIREFOX*****
                for (var lines=0; lines <=252; lines++) {
                    stats[lines].circles.stop().animate({"opacity": ".1"}, 50);
                    if (selectedteam === stats[lines].team) {
                        stats[lines].circles.stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 50);
                    }
                }
            });

        }   
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i don't know if this will work, but just give it a try:
instead of 
  for(var lines=0; lines <=252; lines++)
use:
  for (var lines=-1; ++lines <=252;)

Comment: Is it faster when you change opacity to 0 instead of .1? Just guessing here.

Comment: I've entirely removed the animate() and replaced with a straight changing of the svg attributes. It's still slow! I don't think it's the animate().   Parth Thakkar, replaced the code but still nothing.

Comment: What are the versions of the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari) you are testing in?

Comment: You really ought to pare this code down further to get to the meat of the problem.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 4 and the latest version of Chrome. I'm not sure what the meat of the problem is, Phrogz.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of for loops, when dealing with array indexes, you should use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) javascript's function to iterate an array or, to avoid compatibility issues, when creating the array wrap it with jQuery expression evaluation ( $() or jQuery() ) and use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) jQuery's method to iterate.

Try to perform [this test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/91) in your Firefox to see how it runs.

**UPDATED**

Found a better loop test [here](http://jsperf.com/loops3/2).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Raphael library.  However, I see that the suspect code is wrapped inside a `mouseover` handler.

I've had problems in the past where the same DOM event gets fired differently (or not at all) in different browsers.

Have you considered the possibility that the code could appear to be slow because it is getting invoked multiple times somehow?

I would suggest that you try adding something like this to your page:

```
<span id='counter'>0</span>
```

Then, write

```
var counter = parseInt($('#counter').val()),10);
counter++;
$('#counter').val(counter);
for (var lines=0; lines <=252; lines++) {
    stats[lines].circles.stop().animate({"opacity": ".1"}, 50);
    if (selectedteam === stats[lines].team) {
        stats[lines].circles.stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 50);
    }        
}
```

View the resulting page in different browsers and watch what happens with the counter.

I can't promise you this will help find the problem, but it's what I would try first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I added a counter to the code that fired on `mouseover` and it's firing normally ticking up each time I enter a new circle. Thanks though it is a good thought.

Comment: Okay, then, I would agree with @Phrogz's advice that the next thing to try is to step into the code in your loop and look for something inside the functions you are executing to see if these are running slowing for some or all iterations of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not an "answer" but a solution. Instead of animating the Raphael object's "opacity," I tried editing its "fill-opacity." That significantly sped things up. When I animated both the "fill-opacity" and "fill-stroke," there was still a big speed improvement.

I'm still not sure why animating the opacity change requires so many resources to execute.

Thanks everyone!